# __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR in boost_system and boost_filesystem

Tags: c++, boost, linker, visual-studio-2013

I'm linking the two Boost libraries to the project:

- boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib
- boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib

Both libraries were recompiled locally with the default settings.

The VS2013 linker displays the following messages:

- Debug build:

  - boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(boost_system-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll); second definition ignored
  - boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib(boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.dll) : warning LNK4221: This object file does not define any previously undefined public symbols, so it will not be used by any link operation that consumes this library
- Release build:

  - boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.lib(boost_filesystem-vc120-mt-1_55.dll) : warning LNK4006: __NULL_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR already defined in boost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.lib(boost_system-vc120-mt-1_55.dll); second definition ignored

Should I just ignore these warnings or there is a way on how to fix them?

Comment: Getting boost built is a fair tragedy.  Maybe you should use the [prebuilt binaries](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost-binaries/1.55.0/).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems that the boost_filesystem just includes the boost_system so I've just removed the boost_system from the linker settings. Works well so far.